# Deallocate current VC and push a different VC

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

### Short explanation of the issue:

I have a screen in my app which simulates a room with multiple users in it, and the user can click 'next room' and it will push onto the navigation stack another instance of the room view controller.
This is a memory usage issue for now, because I simply push another instance onto the stack, which leaves the previous room (which is irrelevant) still allocated in memory as it is still in the navigation stack, and it consumes a lot of memory when there are a lot of chat room instances allocated (for example if a user moves to a lot of different rooms).

###### The navigation stack after a user clicks 'next room':

```
LoginViewController: 0x142813e00 // [0] 

TabBarViewController: 0x140836400 // [1] 

LoadingViewController: 0x143813600 // [2]

RoomViewController: 0x13f847400 // [3]

RoomViewController: 0x141824400 // [4]
```

Index 3 should be deallocated after index 4 has been appended to the stack, I do not need index 3 which is the previous room.

---

### What I've tried:

I've implemented a method to clean up the navigation stack after a new 'RoomViewController' has been appended to the navigation stack.

```
func cleanUpNavigationStack() {
   guard let previousRoomVCIndex = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(where: 
   { $0 is RoomViewController }) else {return}
   self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: previousRoomVCIndex)
}
```

I call this method right after pushing the new RoomViewController onto the navigation stack.
So what I've expected to happen is:
1 -> Pushing a new RoomViewController
2 -> Now the navigation stack contains 2 RoomViewControllers, the last one which is the relevant one, and the first one which is the previous irrelevant room.
3 -> I remove the previous irrelevant room from my navigation stack.
4 -> It is being deallocated from memory as well, and if I pop one VC back, it should take me to the LoadingViewController.

But after calling `print(navigationController?.viewControllers)` when I am done cleaning up the navigation stack, I still see the previous RoomViewController, so the removal didn't work for some reason.
What could be the reason for this? and how should I approach it?

My main goal at the end is to deallocate the current RoomVC when pushing a new RoomVC.

Comment: The deallocation message is `deinit`. Did you implement `deinit` to print out a message so you know when a RoomViewController is in fact deallocated? Have you proven that a RoomViewController is _ever_ deallocated? (If not, you likely have a retain cycle that keeps it alive.)

Comment: @matt yes I suspected I might have a retain cycle, the RoomViewController can be dellocated so there’s no retain cycle, but even if there was a retain cycle, why can’t I remove it from the navigation stack array?

Comment: Instead of saying removeAt, try _setting_ the nav controller's array to an array that contains exactly the view controller instances you want.

Comment: This is because an array in Objective-C is _immutable_. The `viewControllers` property is typed as `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *> *viewControllers;` Your `remove(at:)` has no effect on it; it's operating on a _copy_. So perform that operation on your copy and _set the result back into the `viewControllers` property._

Answer (score -2):

You remove screen from array (of Nav Stack), that means this array doesn't hold reference to this screen anymore. But `UINavigationController` still holds a ref `childVC` (this screen), `UIWindow's subview` still holds a ref to this screen's view. It can not be deallocated. That is why we need to call `navigationController.pop...`

The best UX is showing the room list as a Horizontal Page View.

You will need to make a PageItem (can be UICollectionViewCell) and then setup like normal UICollectionView logic.

Or you can use this trick:

Code in `RoomListScreen.swift`

```
import UIKit

class RoomListScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOpenRoom: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func actionDisplayRoomDetail(_ sender: Any) {
        let roomScreen = RoomScreen()
        roomScreen.onOpenNextRoom = { [unowned self] in
            self.handleOnOpenNextRoom()
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomScreen, animated: true)
    }
    
    func handleOnOpenNextRoom() {
        let roomScreen = RoomScreen()
        roomScreen.onOpenNextRoom = { [unowned self] in
            self.handleOnOpenNextRoom()
        }

        // pop current screen (RoomScreen) without animation -> slient popping.
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)

        // If you want to have a nature animation like push new screen, pass true to animated: ..., but the RoomListScreen be visible in 0.2-0.3 seconds, so, it is not good UI/UX. It is acceptable but still confuse user sometime.
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(roomScreen, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Code in `RoomScreen.swift`

```
import UIKit

class RoomScreen: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonNextRoom: UIButton!
    
    var onOpenNextRoom: (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func actionClickNextRoom(_ sender: Any) {
        self.onOpenNextRoom?()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [])
    }
}
```